# Shiny application does not work well when selecting columns

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following problem with the Shiny app. The application has the functionality to import data (excel or csv). Selecting the number of table records and Column selection. Also, if the user wants to import .csv data, a form for entering delimiter will be also shown. The application works well when importing an Excel file but doesn't work well when importing csv. Delimiter entry does not react at all and columns are displayed unsplit in “Select Columns:”

It looks like this:

[image]

How can I fix it?

This is the R code of the shiny application (UI, server and run). You can try to import any csv file:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(shinythemes)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(IRdisplay)
library(shinyjs)
library(bslib) 
library(reactable)




shinyUI(
  tagList(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style.css")
    ),
    navbarPage(
      theme = shinythemes::shinytheme("superhero"), "shinythemes",
      
      tabPanel("Data Sources", 
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                   fileInput("file", "Choose CSV or Excel File",
                             multiple = FALSE,
                             accept = c(
                               "text/csv",
                               "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                               ".csv",
                               ".xlsx",  # Add support for Excel files
                               ".xls"
                             )
                   ),
                   br(),
                   shinyjs::hidden(textInput("delimiter", "Enter Delimiter (e.g., , or ;)", ",")),
                   br(),
                   numericInput("minNumberRow", label = "Display number of rows:", value = 10),
                   selectInput("columns_select", "Select Columns:", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
                 ),
                 
                 mainPanel(
                   tabsetPanel(
                     tabPanel("Tab 1-1",
                              h3("Dobrodošli na prvi tabPanel u prvoj Navbar Page!"),
                              uiOutput("table_1")
                              
                     ),
                     tabPanel("Tab 1-2",
                              h3("Dobrodošli na drugi tabPanel u prvoj Navbar Page!")
                     ),
                     tabPanel("Tab 1-3",
                              h3("Dobrodošli na treći tabPanel u prvoj Navbar Page!")
                     )
                   )
                 )
               )
      ),
      
      tabPanel("Page 2",
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                   p(" sidebarPanel."),
                   
                   div(
                     sliderInput("slider", "Slider input:", 1, 100, 30),
                     class = "my-slider-class" 
                   ),
                   
                 ),
                 mainPanel(
                   tabsetPanel(
                     tabPanel("Tab 2-1",
                              h3("Navbar Page!")
                     ),
                     tabPanel("Tab 2-2",
                              h3(" Navbar Page 2!")
                     ),
                     tabPanel("Tab 2-3",
                              h3(" Navbar Page 3!")
                     )
                   )
                 )
               )
      ),
      
      tabPanel("Page 3",
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(
                   p("Ovo je sidebarPanel za prvi tabsetPanel u trećoj Navbar Page.")
                 ),
                 mainPanel(
                   tabsetPanel(
                     tabPanel("Tab 3-1",
                              h3("Dobrodošli na prvi tabPanel u trećoj Navbar Page!")
                     ),
                     tabPanel("Tab 3-2",
                              h3("Dobrodošli na drugi tabPanel u trećoj Navbar Page!")
                     ),
                     tabPanel("Tab 3-3",
                              h3("Dobrodošli na treći tabPanel u trećoj Navbar Page!")
                     )
                   )
                 )
               )
      )
    )
  )
)




shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    # Toggle delimiter input visibility based on file type
    if (!is.null(input$file) && grepl("\\.csv$", input$file$name)) {
      shinyjs::toggle("delimiter", condition = TRUE)
    } else {
      shinyjs::toggle("delimiter", condition = FALSE)
    }
    
    req(input$file)  # Require the file input before proceeding
    
    # Provjeri je li korisnik odabrao delimiter
    delimiter <- ifelse(nchar(input$delimiter) > 0, input$delimiter, ",")
    
    if (grepl("\\.csv$", input$file$name)) {
      df <- read.csv(input$file$datapath, sep = delimiter, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "")
    } else {
      df <- read_excel(input$file$datapath, sheet = 1, col_names = TRUE)
    }
    # Update reactiveVal with the new data
    data(df)
    # Update the choices for column selection
    updateSelectInput(session, "columns_select", choices = colnames(df), selected = colnames(df))
  })
  
  # Initialize reactiveVal to store the data
  data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  min_rows <- reactive({
    input$minNumberRow
  })
  
  output$table_1 <- renderUI({
    # Dohvati odabrane kolone iz selectInput-a
    selected_columns <- input$columns_select
    
    # Provjeri da li postoje podaci u data i da ima barem jedna kolona
    if (!is.null(data()) && ncol(data()) > 0) {
      # Ako nisu odabrane nikakve kolone, prikaži cijeli DataFrame
      if (is.null(selected_columns) || length(selected_columns) == 0) {
        selected_columns <- colnames(data())
      }
      
      # Filtriraj podatke i prikaži tablicu samo s odabranim kolonama
      reactable(
        data()[, selected_columns, drop = FALSE],
        defaultPageSize = as.numeric(min_rows()),
        filterable = TRUE,
        searchable = TRUE,   # Enable searching in the table
        minRows = 10,        # Set the minimum number of rows to display
        style = list(
          backgroundColor = "#a3bcc0",
          color = "#000000"     # Change the color of the content to blue
        )
      )
    } else {
      # Return an empty reactable if no data is available
      reactable(data.frame(), defaultPageSize = 10)
    }
  })
  
})






ui <- source("ui.R")$value
server <- source("server.R")$value

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This not reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the problem is that your code does not wait for the user to enter the delimiter before reading the file. The conditional has the server send a message to the UI to display the text input and then just continues executing the rest of the `observeEvent` block. It quickly comes to the `read.csv` call and just uses whatever the initial value for `input$delimeter` is. I forget how shiny initializes hidden inputs, but this initial value at best is "," and possibly `NULL`.

What I would do is create a reactive that serves as flag to indicate when the file is ready to read. In the case of an Excel file and the delimiter input is not shown, update the flag in the initial conditional block. Otherwise, wait for it to change then read the file.

```
readyToRead <- reactiveVal()

observeEvent(input$file, {
  # Toggle delimiter input visibility based on file type
  if (!is.null(input$file) && grepl("\\.csv$", input$file$name)) {
    shinyjs::toggle("delimiter", condition = TRUE)
  } else {
    shinyjs::toggle("delimiter", condition = FALSE)
    readyToRead(rnorm(1))
  }
})

observeEvent(input$delimeter,
  readyToRead(rnorm(1))
)

observeEvent(readyToRead, {
  req(input$file)  # Require the file input before proceeding
  
  # Provjeri je li korisnik odabrao delimiter
  delimiter <- ifelse(nchar(input$delimiter) > 0, input$delimiter, ",")
  
  if (grepl("\\.csv$", input$file$name)) {
    df <- read.csv(input$file$datapath, sep = delimiter, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "")
  } else {
    df <- read_excel(input$file$datapath, sheet = 1, col_names = TRUE)
  }
  # Update reactiveVal with the new data
  data(df)
  # Update the choices for column selection
  updateSelectInput(session, "columns_select", choices = colnames(df), selected = colnames(df))
})
```

When to trigger the `readyToRead` flag is a design decision and a separate discussion. For simplicity, I illustrate it as doing it when the input changes, but what if the user wants the default "," and it's not changing? You could remove the default so they have to enter something. Or you could add a confirm button. Or you could use a dialog...the options go on depending on your specific use case. **How** to know when the user is satisfied with the delimiter is a design choice, but waiting until a choice is made should solve your immediate problem.

Comment: I changed the codes but the same thing happens.

Comment: any logical solution please